# Junit cleanup in separate JVM

Tags: unit-testing, maven, ant, jvm, resource-cleanup

Is it possible to run maven or ant in such a way that the @After and @Before tagged methods in a Junit test are run in a separate JVM?  Admittedly, since these normally run once per test case,whose JVM is created externally, I doubt that using these direct annotations could accompany this goal, but , maybe there is a way to define external JVM cleanup and setup directives.

This would allow one to clean system resources even in case the JVM died during a test.

Comment: First @After/@Before are by definition within the same JVM which will run before each test. It sounds like you are working on integration tests instead. Furthermore the question is what kind clean up you need in particular?

Comment: generally any Non JVM resident resources - connections , files, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can set forkmode to "perTest", so that it will create a new VM for each TestCase class: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

But I would prefer to put tests which share JVM to one TestSuite class, and then call batchtest for each of the TestSuites in ant test target.